# Python OpenCV get line in specific HSV range

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I want to analyze ice hockey images and want to obtain the various lines on the playing field. For example, I need to be able to get an image with only the blue line. I have tried to convert the `rgb` image to `hsv` format and have tried to specify the limits between which the `hsv` of each pixel is allowed through a mask. I have then applied the mask to the image. I am getting only a satisfactory output. How can I make the output better? I have tried changing the `hsv` range but a positive impact on one image leads to a negative impact on another.

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Take each frame
frame = cv2.imread('image_name')
# Convert BGR to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# define range of color in HSV
#blue
lower = np.array([110,50,50])
upper = np.array([130,255,255])

# Threshold the HSV image to get only colors
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)

# Bitwise-AND mask and original image
res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)

cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
cv2.imshow('res',res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Outputs:

```
Picture 1 - Image 1 with upper and lower limits as shown in code
Picture 2 - Image 2 with upper and lower limits as shown in code
Picture 3 - Image 1 with upper limit as [130,255,255] and lower limit as [110,20,50] respectively
Picture 4 - Image 2 with upper limit as [130,255,255] and lower limit as [110,20,50] respectively
```

[image]
[image]

Picture 3 and Picture 4:

[Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BlZa.png)
[Picture 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc7MZ.png)

(Sorry, it wasn't allowing me to post more than 2 pictures)

As can be seen, in picture 1, the blue line is not at all solid and contains many gaps. However, when I try to change the saturation for the lower limit, there is too much difference for image 2 which can be seen in picture 4, despite the blue line for image 1 being more solid as can be seen in picture 3.

How can I properly detect the lines and get them in a solid manner? I only need the lines. Please keep in mind that some lines on the field also have slight curves. It would be great if the proposed solution works for them too.

Is this the way to proceed or is there any better way? I ultimately want to get the equations of the individual lines on the field.

Comment: Can you upload the original image? Only the image you are working on and not your results, so I can try something. Also, you can try Lab and Luv color spaces.

Comment: Sure. Here are the two original images: http://imgur.com/a/ItSHp. I will look into Lab and Luv color spaces also. Thanks!